# Error installing sharp with npm on macOS

Tags: npm, sharp

If I create a fresh npm project:

```
mkdir ~/test
cd ~/test
npm init -y
```

And then try to install [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp):

```
npm install --save sharp
```

I get the following error messages:

```
> sharp@0.18.4 install /Users/hsribei/tmp/test/node_modules/sharp
> node-gyp rebuild

sh: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: Permission denied
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! sharp@0.18.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.18.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hsribei/.npm/_logs/2017-09-20T19_11_03_836Z-debug.log
```

I've found instructions to delete `~/.node-gyp`, tried that, didn't work. Deleting `node_modules` and trying again also doesn't work. Running as `sudo` doesn't help either.

Any ideas in how I can trace what the problem is?

Answer (score 8):

I found out there is a missing global dependency for `sharp`.

If you run

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

**first**, then

```
npm install --save sharp
```

It works.